# `helmfile diff` returns "Release was not present in Helm. Diff will show entire contents as new."

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

```
********************

    Release was not present in Helm.  Diff will show entire contents as new.

********************
```

If I am interpreting this right, this means that there's no diff between a local state and the deployment in the cluster. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the opposite, this means `helm` didn't find such release in the cluster and `diff` will show you entire contents as new vs only showing you differences.

At any point you can do `helm list` to see what releases you have deployed.